# Simplify CSS for Table Column Width Control

Tags: css

Thanks for the stackoverflow community, I have found a solution to my question, which is also my first question on stackoverflow.

I am not a front-end professional who is familiar with CSS, I just want to maintain a simple WordPress site and need to control some table formats for better readability. So it would be too difficult for me to read through the CSS documentary to find a solution for a very specific question, that's why I ask the question here.

Also, I feel there must be some "CSS geek" around the stackoverflow community, they might give some "tricks" on handling this which was even not covered by the CSS documentary, but might be more concise and smart.

Now I know this kind of question might be too basic for stackoverflow community. This experience provide me a rough standard on what question might be appropriate here. Thanks!

---

### my initial question:

I am using Tablepress for generating table in WordPress. Each column can be assigned with a min-width respectively. But if I want to do the same setting to more than one column, I need to repeat the same CSS code again and again? Is it possible to merge them into one CSS block instead of three CSS block?

```
.tablepress-id-1 .column-1 {
    min-width: 100px;
}

.tablepress-id-1 .column-2 {
    min-width: 100px;
}

.tablepress-id-1 .column-3 {
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

### some progress after more investigation

I find it can be simplified into the following format:

```
.tablepress-id-1 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-1 .column-2,
.tablepress-id-1 .column-3 {
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

But can it be further simplified as ".tablepress-id-1" still repeated many times.

### my solution

The table is generated by a plugin "TablePress" in WordPress, its official documentary said, the property of each column can be controlled by (x is the column number):

```
.tablepress-id-1 .column-x {
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

But I have many columns in the table and many tables in a site, so if I need to set a min-width to each column, I need to prepare a long CSS file with many duplicated CSS command.

I am not a professional of CSS, but it is reasonable to guess some repeated part can be merged or shortened to simplify the CSS file. First, I tried something like (and other combinations):

```
.tablepress-id-1 .column-1, .column-2, .column-3 {
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

But seems not working, so I asked the question here. Later, I found it can be reduced to:

```
.tablepress-id-1 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-1 .column-2,
.tablepress-id-1 .column-3 {
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

But still, I see a lot of repeated commands, and thanks to [beingalex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387761/beingalex), who mentioned using tr and td to control the column. Then I tried and found the following CSS is the most compact one (as far as I can see):

```
.tablepress-id-1 td,
.tablepress-id-1 th {
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

If I need to further increase the min-width of some column, I can add one previous block. For example, all the column now have a min-width of 100px, and I want the first column to be at least 150px, I can add this into CSS:

```
.tablepress-id-1 .column-1 {
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

It seems to be a good solution for me now. And I hope this can help others with similar questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about the basics of CSS. You should read a tutorial

Comment: I found a way to simplify it into one block, but can I further reduce the duplicated parts?

Comment: *"Tablepress for generating table in wordpress"* is it generating these classes or do you have the ability to add any classes anywhere?

Comment: Tablepress generate the table and comes with these classes, and I need to modify some property to the table by these classes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question, it is an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the > selector.

This selector targets the next child.

```
.tablepress-id-1 > tr > td {
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

I upvoted your question as you did investigate. And this is a question and answer site.

Comment: Thank you. I found tr and td is the most compact way solve my problem, I updated my solution in the question. Thanks again.